# Adding elevation data to a network dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network, elevation

I am trying to add elevation data to my road network to more accurately calculate walking distance to and from schools. I have figured out how to do the network with out elevation, but for the life of I can't figure out how to add in the elevation (hills etc).

I have currently have:

- Road Network Feature Class
- Road Infrastructure Feature Class
- Contour Lines 1-5m Feature Class
- TIN and DEM models produced from the
  contour lines

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Ah sorry, Arc Map 10.2

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Run field calculator expression (Python) on numeric field type double:

```
def plineZ(shp):
 part=shp.getPart(0)
 n=len(part);L=0;p1=part.getObject(0)
 for i in xrange(1,n):
  p2=part.getObject(i)
  dX=p2.X-p1.X;dY=p2.Y-p1.Y;dZ=p1.Z-p2.Z
  l=dX*dX+dY*dY+dZ*dZ
  L+=pow(l,0.5)
  p1=p2
 return L


plineZ( !Shape!)
```

To get this:

[image]

Comment: I cant seem to get the python script to work, what application should I use?

Comment: Field calculator. Python

Comment: I am not that familiar with python, so I think I am doing it wrong as it keep throwing up syntax errors

Comment: You need nil knowledge of Python to make it work. Have a look at Using code blocks http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/ . Copy 1st nine lines into first box, copy  plineZ(!Shape!) into second narrow text box. Check Python, click Ok